# Why my Time Capsule shared drive keeps refreshing?

Tags: time-capsule

I use my Time Capsule to share files across my machines.

On my MacBook, when I open the shared disk in Finder, and expand some folders, it starts to "refresh" after a few seconds again and again.

If I click on a file, it loses the selection, and the directory tree disappear and appear, like being unmounted and mounted quickly.

Edit: I realized that what was causing that was some folders with accent in their names (like: Música). Once I removed the accent, this behavior stopped. Is this a known bug?

Comment: Can you load the console app and see if there are any relevant Finder or backupd error messages under 'All Messages'? Nice profile pic btw - reboot?

Comment: I edited the question with more relevant information, and yes, reboot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a known (or at least widely observed) bug with the Finder trying to display files with non-latin characters in their names on an AFP server (like the Time Capsule) -- see http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2426415 for example.

Comment: Broken link now.